# MySQL using function IN with variable

Tags: mysql

I have problem querying table with variable in IN function.

```
SELECT 
    s.date,
    (SELECT
         GROUP_CONCAT(value) 
         FROM value 
         WHERE id_value 
         IN(s.ref_values)
    ) AS vals
FROM stats s
ORDER BY s.date DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Where `s.ref_values` is `'12,22,54,15'`. I get only one return for first number (12).

When I insert that value directly in `IN(12,22,54,15)` it finds all 4.

So, there must be problem with using variable in `IN`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite your query to

```
SELECT 
s.date,
(SELECT
     GROUP_CONCAT(value) 
     FROM value 
     WHERE id_value 
     IN(SELECT ref_values FROM stats)
) 
AS vals
FROM stats s
ORDER BY s.date DESC
LIMIT 1
```

and see if that helps.

You should ideally be passing a result set as a parameter to `IN`

Comment: Same result :-(. I can get extra (first) query for ref_values, but it is complicated when I want to have it for each row.

Comment: Still facing the same problem?